# iOS App Advertisement choice : iAd or AdMob ?

Tags: ios

what will you choose , iAd or AdMob ? and what is the reason behind ?

I'm now using iAd, as I think Apple may block AdMob anytime, as Apple wants to protect its iAd. Is it true?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. To avoid getting answers that don't really solve your problem, the question will be closed FOR NOW until it can be improved. Please edit your question to make it clearer so we can reopen it. Read [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more ideas to improve the question. Confusing questions are closed so they don't attract a scattering of answers before they're in a form that is likely to get a clear answer; your question can be reopened at any time if you or someone on your behalf suitably amends it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to combine both in the same iOS app.
[This](http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_mixing_ads.php) URL will provide you more information about this issue.

Summary: 
You try to load iAd, if that fails to load or something else happens - you can fall back on AdMob.